# Python: While loop runs once and waits.. I want it to loop but it does not

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi

I am new to python coding and I am using a Raspberry Pi as means of learning. I am trying to continuously poll the inputs on my board and print them to the screen, however the code prints the input states once and seems to wait for something and I can't seem to figure it out... any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# piFace_Control.py

import piface.pfio as pfio
import serial
import time
import struct

def h(val):
    return struct.pack('!H', val)

def i(val):
    return struct.pack('I', val)

serialA = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
serialA.open()
serialA.flush()

pfio.init()

time.sleep(1)

val2 = 1
run = 1

while (run):
      try:
        val = serialA.readline()
        print(val)
        serialA.write(h(0xFE))
        serialA.write(' Got it!')

        if val2 == 0:
            val2 = 1
        else:
            val2 = 0 

        print(i(val2))
        serialA.write(i(val2))
        pfio.digital_write(0,val2)
        print "D0: "+str(pfio.digital_read(0))
        print "D1: "+str(pfio.digital_read(1))
        print "D2: "+str(pfio.digital_read(2))
        print "D3: "+str(pfio.digital_read(3))
        print "D4: "+str(pfio.digital_read(4))
        print "D5: "+str(pfio.digital_read(5))
        print "D6: "+str(pfio.digital_read(6))
        print "D7: "+str(pfio.digital_read(7))

      except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print '\nKeyboard Interrupt Caught...'
        run = 0
        pass

serialA.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit:

```
val = serialA.readline()
```

On the second loop, it never recieves a complete line from the serial, waiting until it does.

Whatever is sitting on the other end of the serial connection is sending only one line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize that function would wait... Is there a way for me to check the buffer and bypass that line if there is nothing?

Comment: I don't know much about it but have seen (eg) `ser=serial.Serial('/dev/USB0', 9600, timeout=1)` ie a serial timeout

Comment: Its not as simple as checking a buffer. I can have a serial connection that sends a steady stream of `a`s, and that call will still hang, as the line never ends. Not sure if the timeout argument solves thay

Comment: I advise to not use `.readline()` or anything similar (like read until byte `x` occurs), if you don't mind the chance of being blocked. A good way around this problem without the timeout here is to use `.read()` like this: `serialA.read(serialA.inWaiting())` which reads everything in the incoming buffer of the serial connection or nothing.